# How to use Mysql ORDER BY Case to arrange the queries results

Tags: mysql

I have this query in which I included a `case` statement:

```
SELECT
    tsp_filtered_data.increment_id,
    tsp_filtered_data.ESN,
    tsp_filtered_data.Model,
    tsp_filtered_data.Fault,
    CASE 
       WHEN tsp_filtered_data.ESN RLIKE '^[0-9A-F]{8}$' 
          THEN 'valid ESN' 
          ELSE 'Invalid ESN'  
    END AS ESN_status 
FROM
    tsc_document_status
INNER JOIN 
    tsp_filtered_data ON tsp_filtered_data.Document_id = tsc_document_status.warehouse_transfer_note_id
ORDER BY 
    tsp_filtered_data.ESN DESC
```

and it returns this output:

[image]

Can I use those results of 'valid ESN' and 'Invalid ESN' in to order by

my requirement is to place all the 'Invalid ESN' lists to the top of the queried results, while next the 'Valid ESN' list.

how can i do the modification to the query..

Comment: `ORDER BY ESN_status, tsp_filtered_data.ESN DESC `

Answer (score 3):

Use `ORDER BY FIELD`:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(ESN_status, 'Invalid ESN', 'Valid ESN')
```

Full query:

```
SELECT
    t2.increment_id,
    t2.ESN,
    t2.Model,
    t2.Fault,
    CASE WHEN t1.ESN RLIKE '^[0-9A-F]{8}$'
         THEN 'Valid ESN' ELSE 'Invalid ESN' END AS ESN_status 
FROM tsc_document_status t1
INNER JOIN tsp_filtered_data t2
    ON t1.Document_id = t2.warehouse_transfer_note_id
ORDER BY
    ORDER BY FIELD(ESN_status, 'Invalid ESN', 'Valid ESN')
```

Note that I introduced table aliases which leaves your query easier to read (IMO).  You are free to add more levels of sorting to your `ORDER BY` clause, though my answer should address what you requested in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    tsp_filtered_data.increment_id,
    tsp_filtered_data.ESN,
    tsp_filtered_data.Model,
    tsp_filtered_data.Fault,
    case when tsp_filtered_data.ESN RLIKE '^[0-9A-F]{8}$' then 'valid ESN' else 'Invalid ESN'  end AS ESN_status 
    FROM
    tsc_document_status
    INNER JOIN tsp_filtered_data ON tsp_filtered_data.Document_id = tsc_document_status.warehouse_transfer_note_id
    ORDER BY ESN_status,tsp_filtered_data.ESN DESC      //Modified line
```

What it will do is that first,it will sort the whole result set in Ascending order of `ESN_status`. Now, for the records having same `ESN_status`, it will sort them in descending order of `tsp_filtered_data.ESN`

Hope it helps!